# Hibernate criteria calculation of two columns

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a class called task which is as:

```
public class task {
    int id;
    Date dueDate;
    int treshold;
}
```

treshold is how much hour before dueDate user want to get notification in terms of hour. I created a quartz job which starts every hour and should get all task which are as follows

now > dueDate-treshold

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate `calculatedThreshold = now - dueDate`.

Then use one of 2:

1. Citeria:

   ```
   List result = session.createCriteria(task.class).
                         add(Expression.ge("threshold", calculatedThreshold).
                         list();
   ```
2. HQL:

   ```
   List result = session.createQuery(
                 "from task where threshold >= :calculatedThreshold").
        setParameter("calculatedThreshold", calculatedThreshold).
        list();
   ```

Comment: The problem is that, due date is different for every task so direct calculation don't work as expected, i guess calculation should be done within query

Comment: Where do you pull those due dates from? Is that another Hibernate mapped entity? If yes, you can do a join query between the 2 entities and make the calculation in the where part of the query.

Comment: i want to create an sql query as: 'select * from task as t where t.treshold > :now - t.dueDate'